# python list amended unknowingly

Tags: python

I am new to coding and I started some leetcode. I am not very sure why the list changed when it's in the second if statement

```
class Solution(object):
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    for x in nums:
        y = 0
        y = target - x 
        if y in nums:
            if x == y:
                try:
                    number_index = nums.index(x)
                    del nums[number_index]
                    return [number_index, (nums.index(y)+1)]
                except:
                    continue
            elif nums.index(y) != nums.index(x):
                return [nums.index(x), nums.index(y)]
```

[image: List changed after if statment]

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I've tried to debug by printing it out but I don't get the rationale behind the amended list....

Comment: Don't ignore the exception. It might have helpful information.

Comment: "Printing it out" is not the same as debugging. Did you try using an actual debugger, or a tool like Python Tutor that I linked above? Stepping through the code and checking where things go wrong? If you would, you would see that on the first iteration `x` and `y` are both `3`. After the `del` statement, 3 is not anymore in the list so `nums.index(y)` fail